# are there macros in python like that in c?

Tags: python-3.x, macros

My question is that just like in C Language we define macros as:

## define pi=3.14

so i want to inquire is there a way in python also that we can define here..
right now i am directly assigning values to the variables at the start of my program like pi=3.14

and use 'pi' everywhere instead of 3.14..although it is working fine until now..but is there a concept of preprocessor directives or MACROS in python also..if yes then how can we define it?

i have directly used a variable like route_Head_len=8
and used it in the functions where i want this value 8

i am getting the results which i want..`routeHead_len=8
def readRouteHead():
    route_Head=[]
    for i in range(routeHead_len):
        route_Head.append(data[i])
    return route_Head

a=readRouteHead()
print("Route Head: ",a)`

Comment: There is no preprocessor in Python, and so no preprocessor directives, either. Also, no macros. Using a variable is the correct way.

Comment: Also you can `from math import pi`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe sir 'pi' was just for example i took..i have some other names which i want to pre defined before the start of program..so was just confirming whether there are macros in python or declaring them through a variable will done the same job for me..

Comment: @Amadan..ok sir thank you so much